# Should a cookie with the host-only-flag replace a cookie without it?

Tags: http, cookies

[RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) states that a user-agent should proceed in the following way when receiving a Set-Cookie header:

If the Domain attribute is set:

- Set the cookie's domain to the domain-attribute.
- Set the cookie's host-only-flag to `false`.

If the Domain attribute is **not** set:

- Set the cookie's domain to the canonicalized request-host.
- Set the cookie's host-only-flag to `true`.

This is all clear. The confusion comes with this paragraph:

> If the user agent receives a new cookie with the same cookie-name,
> domain-value, and path-value as a cookie that it has already stored,
> the existing cookie is evicted and replaced with the new cookie.

Let's take an example, with two cookies received on the domain `www.example.com`:

```
Set-cookie: name=value
Set-Cookie: name=value; Domain=www.example.com
```

The domain (and path) will be the same for both cookies, but the first one will have the host-only-flag set to `true`, and the second one to `false`.

Reading the RFC, it looks like it doesn't matter when comparing the two cookies, and they should be considered equivalent anyway, but I'm not sure my interpretation is correct.

**Should the user-agent replace the first cookie with the second one, or should it store both of them?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paragraph that confuses you is about the **ability to assign a new value** to a cookie (as well as changing/refreshing the cookie expiration date). If it were not written that way, the HTTP client would need to store multiple cookies with the same name could and it would need to decide on another criterium which to send to the HTTP server upon the next request.

Regarding the second part of your question:

If those two cookies are specified within the same request, the second one "wins", therefore a cookie with the `host-only-flag = false` would be stored.

If those two cookies come in separate requests, the second one overwrites the first one, because they match in cookie-name (specified), domain-value (once specified, once derived), and path-value (derived). When storing them, the entries in the browser's cookie database only differ in the host-only-flag.

This host-only-flag comes into effect when the client issues a new request to the server ([snippet from RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)):

```
The user agent MUST use an algorithm equivalent to the following
algorithm to compute the "cookie-string" from a cookie store and a
request-uri:

1.  Let cookie-list be the set of cookies from the cookie store that
    meets all of the following requirements:

    *  Either:

           The cookie's host-only-flag is true and the canonicalized
           request-host is identical to the cookie's domain.

        Or:

           The cookie's host-only-flag is false and the canonicalized
           request-host domain-matches the cookie's domain.
```

The fine detail is in how the domain is compared. The matching algorithm is specified in [section 5.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.3).

Essentially you can have a cookie be valid for all subdomains if the domain is specified with a leading "."

When the domain is omitted, though, (and therefore implied by the server from the request), this can never be the case because there always needs to be an identical match in the domain.

**Further research determined:**

In practice browsers store a domain that has been specified in the cookie with a prepended `.` (for `www.example.com` it will store `.www.example.com`) so that a request to `subdomain.www.example.com` will also return that cookie. When no domain is specified the plain domain without a prepended `.` will be stored, thus a request to a subdomain will not include that cookie.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The sentence quoted in my question also confuses me about whether to take into account the request-host and request-path when comparing the two cookies: for example, if I receive the same cookie twice, without a `Path` attribute, on two different request-paths, should I consider the two cookies equivalent (the second one replaces the first one), or different (both are stored)?

Comment: Both are stored. If the path is omitted, it is implied by the request. It then only replaces an existing cookie if the paths match. I suppose many web deveopers can painfully confirm this behavior as it can give you headaches if you don't use the path when setting a cookie while the script is executed in a subdirectory.

Comment: Just confirmed this behaviour on Chrome indeed!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the second part of your answer though: you're saying that I'm correct in my interpretation, where I say that two cookies only differing by the host-only-flag should be considered equal (could override each other), but then you say that both of them should be stored (therefore implying they're not equivalent, and can't override each other). Could you please clarify this point?

Comment: Well, if the server sends both `Set-Cookie` headers in the same response, the client *theoretically* should store both Cookies, one with the host-only-flag and one without. This is quite unusual, though.

Comment: Yes, this is what happens when I test it in Chrome. But the thing is, I can't find a mention to this in RFC6265!

Comment: Why? It is exactly what you quoted in your question.

Comment: But remember that it also says: `A user agent MAY ignore a received cookie in its entirety.  For example, the user agent might wish to block receiving cookies from "third-party" responses or the user agent might not wish to store cookies that exceed some size.`

Comment: Not quite, it says `with the same cookie-name, domain-value, and path-value`. I don't know if that means "the domain-value and path-value as shown in the Set-Cookie header", or "the domain and path as computed along with the request-host and request-path". I would tend to understand the latter, as we said that an empty path on two different request-path produces two different cookies. So if we apply this theory to the domain, that would be "the domain computed from the `Domain` attribute *and* the request-host", without a mention to the host-only-flag...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29598/discussion-between-akirk-and-benjamin)

Comment: I'm awarding you the bounty to avoid missing the expiration date, but waiting for some input from you on the chat to mark as accepted :) Thanks.